# How to change the date format 19000101 to 01.01.1900 in Excel?

Tags: excel, date

I simply have a US data file containg some information. As it wasn't properly formatted I split the different parts of each cell using the text to column function.

The problem I now face is that the date format is yearmonthday (e.g. 19000101) without any seperator like . or -. I need to transform it into the German style day.month.year (e.g. 01.01.1900). So far all my formatting attemps failed probably because it recognizes it as a number instead of a date.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You can use text to columns

Comment: Somehow it didn't work even though I read a douzen times that it should do the trick. Still thanks for your help

Comment: It's very easy. Select your data > Text to columns > Fixed (no delimiters, no boundaries) > Next > Choose: Date (YMD) and confirm. Then custom format your column `dd.mm.yyyy`. Done

Comment: Honestly I've no idea why but I tried it probably 20x and it doesn't work. although I the problem's already solved I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I'll try put up some screenshots, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through some simpe `Text To Columns`:

[image]

**1.** Select your data

**2.** Goto `Data` > `Text to Columns`

**3.** Choose `Fixed width` > Click `Next`

**4.** Do not use any break lines > Click `Next`

**5.** Under "Column data format" tick `Date` and choose `YMD`

**6.** Under destination choose `$A$1` > Click 'Confirm`.

**7.** Result as per screenshot (depending on your locale, this may differ)

**8.** Right click range > `Properties` > `Custom Format` > `DD.MM.YYYY` > `Ok`

Comment: Although I solved it before, thanks for your effort! Big thinking error on my side, I chose the desired output format DMY instead of data format YMD. Simply overread it (multiple times). Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

If bad-format data is in column A, use `=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))` to convert it from string to a real date, then format it as you like.